# How to delete folder with images and mysql record news that does not exist

Tags: php, mysql

How to delete folder with images and mysql record news that does not exist?
Dont work. Why?

```
$resnotid = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id FROM objects");

$idarray[] = array(); 
$namefolderarray[] = array(); 

while($rownotid = mysqli_fetch_array($resnotid)) {
    $idarray[] = $rownotid['id'];
}

$dir = opendir('upload');
while($folder = readdir($dir)) {
   if (is_dir('upload/'.$folder) && $folder != '.' && $folder != '..') {
        $namefolderarray[] = $folder;
   }
}

$delid = array_diff($namefolderarray, $idarray);
rmdir('upload/'.$delid.'/');
```

Comment: Please do not create a new user just to repost a question https://stackoverflow.com/q/56060114/1011527

Comment: Please explain what this code should do, what it currently does **not** do, and what you've tried to debug this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) returns an array. So you have to iterate over that array.

```
$del_arr = array_diff($namefolderarray, $idarray);
foreach ($del_arr as $delid) {
    rmdir('upload/'.$delid.'/');
}
```

**Update 1**

The previous solution only works for empty folders. If you have any content in the folders you must first delete the content. This can be done with an recursive function that iterates over the contents.

```
function rmdir_recursively($path) {
    if (is_dir($path)){
        $list = glob($path.'*', GLOB_MARK);
        foreach($list as $item) {
            rmdir_recursively($item);      
        }
        rmdir($path);
    } else if (is_file($path)) {
        unlink($path);  
    }
}

$del_arr = array_diff($namefolderarray, $idarray);
foreach ($del_arr as $del_id) {
    rmdir_recursively('upload/'.$del_id.'/');
}
```

**Update 2**

To also delete the database-records without a folder you can extend the code like this:

```
foreach ($del_arr as $del_id) {
    rmdir_recursively('upload/'.$del_id.'/');
    $del_id_escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($del_id);
    mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM objects WHERE id='$del_id_escaped'");
}
```

Comment: Does not delete all folders that do not have an id match.

Comment: What kind of folders get not deleted. Can you provide some information/examples about the IDs used in the database and the names of the folders? Maybe you have a problem with case-sensitive characters or character-encoding.

Comment: That delete only empty folders. How detele folders also with attachments?

Comment: I updated my answer with an version that recursively iterates over the content and deletes the files and folders inside the path provided.

Comment: How also delete from MYSQL?

Comment: You can just query the database inside the foreach-loop with a delete-command. I updated my answer with a code-example.